# Why is the Voltage only 1.4 for reset input when in high impedance?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, programmer, parallel-port

I attempted to make myself a 2-in-1 programmer so I can program both AT89Cx051 and AT89S52 on the same board without having to do so much plugging/unplugging of the port.

[image: circuit]

The main issue is the strobe pin aka reset (RST in circuit). (pin 1 of the DB25 connector). I tested it with a PC and got no results.

What seems to somewhat work is if I connected RST to VCC via a 1K resistor. It somewhat works because even though the output is only at 3.8V instead of 5 (which VCC is also at), it puts the AT89S52 in reset mode as expected, but I'm not getting 12V at pin 1 of the small AT89Cx051 socket.

If I don't make the manual connection, then I get 1.4V measured at RST, even after I added a 10K resistor between VCC and RST. Without RST being forced to ground, I should get 5V but I'm not.

I have also tested the transistors manually from leg to leg using the diode setting on the multimeter and they turned out fine. The resistors going to the base of the transistors are 2.2K and I used 1K resistors in place of the diodes. All other resistors are 10K. The resistor going into the buffer (74HC125) is 0 ohm.

All capacitors are 0.1uF.

Why would I be getting such awkward voltages for reset pin?
Am I using too weak of resistors or something?

**UPDATE**

So I ended up making myself an ms-dos 6.22 bootdisk and booted my machine into that with qbasic to test the parallel port (with port at address 278-27AH ) in general with simple circuitry and that seems to work decently.

When I teted only the parallel port on the pc with only a voltmeter with anode lead connected to the strobe pin, I get the following results:

```
Qbasic code           Result
OUT &H27A, 0          4V output from strobe
OUT &H27A, 1          0V output from strobe
```

When I plugged my circuit into the port, the voltage dropped:

```
Qbasic code           Result
OUT &H27A, 0          1.56V output from strobe
OUT &H27A, 1          0V output from strobe
```

How is it possible I'm only getting 1.56V from that pin?

**update 2**

I disconnected the 12V line from the circuit and the voltages on the reset line are now 1.52V and 0V

Comment: These diagrams are very confusing. How exactly are the two connected (assuming they are connected)?

Comment: `I tested it with a PC and got no results.` ... what does this even mean?

Comment: What's the voltage on X2, pin 1? If there is an external pull-up on that line it may be turning on T1 somewhat and pulling RST low.

Comment: jsotola. it means I was expecting some kind of reaction to my circuit as a result of using the PC to change the strobe value but it seemed nothing happened. I could blame the PC since the tests were done in Windows XP. I'm looking at putting on a DOS partition to help me troubleshoot better once I figure out why I have a low voltage problem

Comment: and Transistor, that voltage is the same. as the reset line since it is connected. I used a 10K pull-up so I figured with the circuit not plugged into the computer, the voltage on that line should be 5V thanks to the 10K resistor but I'm not getting 5V.

Comment: `I was expecting some kind of reaction to my circuit as a result of using the PC to change the strobe value but it seemed nothing happened.` is also a useless description .... something like `I tested it with a PC and measured only 1.5V on the collector of T1` is what you should be posting

Comment: And for the diagram, I separated the two circuits to illustrate that I have 2 programmers. The only connections the right-most circuit has to the parallel port are data bits 1 and 2 to control clock and data, strobe line as the reset line, and select-in line as data out. and VCC and ground.

Comment: jsotola, I'm taking the PC out of the equation right now because the reset line isn't of the right voltage (without the PC connected)

Comment: When I was making the PCB, I made the outer ground plate on the port itself disconnected from the rest of the circuit. I'm tempted to connect them to circuit ground but then again that wouldn't fix my immediate issue?

Comment: Note this will only likely work with with an actual local bus parallel port such as is nearly extinct.  It **will not** work with 99% of USB printer adapters.  Additionally, it will not work with ordinary printer drivers active - you may need a time-domain instrument like an oscilloscope to tell if the 1.4v is a steady intermediate value or the time average of pulsing.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are missing a 10 K pull-up resistor in series with a 1N4148 diode at the reset pin of the MPU itself. You show CRESET as being there for programming the IC, but no 3.3 volt pull up which MUST be there. Your reset transistor needs a current on its collector at all times or the IC may stay in reset state.
2. The diode is to prevent 12 volts from going back into the Vcc 3.3 volt line during programing.
3. Pin 1 of your DB25 connector should have a 10 K resistor to ground so the reset transistor does not turn ON due to leakage currents.
4. To reset the IC you need to ground its RESET pin or connect pin1 of the DB25 connector to Vcc. At least that should be your goal.
5. I am not sure where or why you get 1.4 volts on the reset pin. First of all your are not defining *which* reset pin. The IC or the DB25 pin 1. Plus you are missing important pull-up and pull-down resistors so by my standards the 1.4 volts is just leakage current.
6. I am sure you will see the 1.4 volt reading change and be more sensible once you install the resistors and diode I mentioned.
7. You missed a couple of important steps that should get it working correctly, at least the RESET function anyways.
8. In all honesty your diagram is a bit confusing. I am only looking at the left schematic with the DB25 connector, which you have pin1 as RESET if it is high. It cannot be open collector unless it is a PNP transistor because T1 must have its base pulled low or it will reset the MPU.
9. You are sooo close to having it right. Yes the diode is forward biased from a 3.3 or 5 volt line, through the 10 K resistor. This insures that the MPU RESET pin is held high, yet can still act as a programming pin. The 3 pin connector should NOT be used unless you are programming the MPU.

Comment: I guess my schematic wasn't clear. that resistor labelled CRESET is 2.2K which connects to +12VDC. the 3-pin jumper is the power connection. And the diode needs to be the 1N400x forward biased I guess? I'm not sure what 3.3V you're referring to but my circuit uses 5V mostly (but 12V for AT89Cx051 reset pin). I will consider trying point #3, but isn't the strobe line (pin 1) for parallel port open-collector? The reset line I'm having an issue with is the one connected to parallel port pin 1. I'm unsure why I need pull-downs. I'm trying to comply with port standards unless they changed?

Comment: In all honesty your diagram is a bit confusing. I am only looking at the left schematic with the DB25 connector, which you have pin1 as RESET if it is high. It cannot be open collector unless it is a PNP transistor because T1 must have its base pulled low or it will reset the MPU. You are sooo close to having it right. Yes the diode is forward biased from a 3.3 or 5 volt line, through the 10 K resistor. This insures that the MPU RESET pin is held high, yet can still act as a programming pin. The 3 pin connector should NOT be used unless you are programming the MPU.

Comment: I added the above comment to the answer.

Comment: That is the intention of this whole board to be able to program both microcontrollers. I have NPN for T1 because then the plan is reset pin can see 12V (programming mode) if NPN base is low or 0V if the NPN base is high. I don't understand where the 3.3V is coming from unless theres some resistor network I made that I'm not seeing?

Comment: and the open collector I'm referring to is what's in a parallel port at the PC end. I got the info here: http://retired.beyondlogic.org/spp/parallel.htm and it states: "The printer would not send a signal to initialize the computer, nor would it tell the computer to use LF. However these outputs can also be used as inputs. If the computer has placed a pin high (e.g. +5v) and your device wanted to take it low, you would effectively short out the port. Therefore these lines are "open collector" outputs. This means that it has two states. A low state (0v) and a high impedance state."

Comment: the outputs refer to linefeed and I think strobe as well. It's about 1/3 way down the page on that site. I don't know if that information is still accurate but If I connect the resistors to the wrong end of the power line (example: ground instead of vcc) then the circuit might not recognize signals coming from the computer

Comment: Then your open collector driving pin 1 of the DB25 connector MUST stay low or it will cause T1 to reset the MPU. I noted that you could use 5 volts if 3.3 is not available.

Comment: It is very late. I am going to bed. Good luck.